creates a GLPI Icare ticket when an e-mail is received
I would like to realize a GLPI ticket automation project. I would like that when I receive an email on an email address, it creates a ticket on GLPI Icare.
The mailbox is a shared box. How can I do this?
Is it possible to help me automate this?
